# Connect woocommerce to an API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a problem to find the correct dynamic variable in woocommerce which works with this API,In this API i need to send product Id and Order count which i dont know the correct variable for them in woocommerce.
please tell me the correct dynamic variable of Product ID and Order count in woocommerce.

This is my API:

```
    const options2 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "SettleTypeId": `STID`,
            "RRN": `RNN`,
            "ApMerchantId:": `MerchantID`,
            "Products":
            [
                {
                    "ProductId":`${?}`,
                    "OrderCount":`${?}`
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    
    fetch('URL', options2)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Localstorage for that. You can Store productID and Order Count in localStorage and get here.

```js
 const options2 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "SettleTypeId": `STID`,
            "RRN": `RNN`,
            "ApMerchantId:": `MerchantID`,
            "Products":
            [
                {
                    "ProductId":`${localStorage.getItem("ID")}`,
                    "OrderCount":`${localStorage.getItem("OrderCount")}`
                }
            ]
        }
    }

fetch(URL, data)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: First of all Thanks second, could you please tell me where can I find all purchase variables for woocommerce? I need a dynamic variables for RRN too.
And this code in only for one Product how can I write it for all products which are in the user cart.